# dnx and asp.net 5 compiling for distribution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

When I use dnx I can run the command `dnu build` which generates a DLL from my Console Application. How can I re-use that in another computer e.g. linux? As I understood, I must include the project.json so that in the linux I will run `dnu restore` but I can't understand how do I run it without the code because when I run `dnx . run` I get

> 'ConsoleApplication' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
>   for an entry point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently you can use `dnx --lib path/to/output/dir . run` with your project.json of course and it will load your dll's from that folder, without the source code available on the server.

posting this so it might help someone